# How to create python2.7 virtualenv on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python-2.7, virtualenv

I want to run an application that uses python2.7 version, but by default python2.7 is not installed. When I tried to use:

```
$ virtualenv -p python2 flaskold
```

It returned:

```
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python2'
```

How could I create python2.7 virtual environment on Ubuntu 20.04 which goes without python 2.7 support?

Comment: I understand what the question is from reading its answer, but I think this question could be improved by editing the question to make it more explicit.

Comment: Why not just install `python-is-python2` package and use as normal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install python2:

```
sudo apt install python2 virtualenv
```

Universe repository is being used for this. You could add it if not added the next way: `$ sudo add-apt-repository universe`.

Create virtual environment using python2.7 the next way:

```
$ virtualenv --python=$(which python2) /path/to/newenv/folder/
```

`$(which python2)` will return path to python2 which would be correct argument. `python2` could be used to start interpreter in terminal, but could not be used as an argument value for `--python` directive

Comment: Works. And yes, you need to create the directory of the venv yourself, that is, installing a venv does not create a parent venv folder on its own.

Answer (score 1):

For Python3

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
```

For Python2

```
sudo pip2 install virtualenv
```