# Ubuntu 20.04 - need Python 2 - native Python 2 install vs other options?

Tags: 20.04, python-2.7

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 for a few months now and things are going well, however recently I ran into 2 legacy applications which I'll need to start supporting that will require Python 2.  As best as I can figure, I have at least the following choices:

- Go back to Ubuntu 18.04.5
- Install Python 2 in Ubuntu 20.04
- Attempt to install Python 2 in Ubuntu 20.04 but only in a virtual environment
- Use a VM

I'd prefer to stay away from the VM option b/c I use GPUs frequently which won't go through a VM and also b/c I do a lot of hardware/software interfacing for which using a VM may cause various problems.  Also I don't like VMs generally (crashes, mouse/keyboard/screen hiccups, slow performance, etc.)

I'll be honest and admit I don't use virtual environments much, however I can say I'm not inclined towards this option as the 2 legacy applications I'm going to be supporting call Python various places (calling files that start new processes, etc.) that I suspect a virtual environment won't be able to handle.  Also, I'v read about problems with an entire separate version of Python in a virtual environment, ex [How to create python2.7 virtualenv on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296611/how-to-create-python2-7-virtualenv-on-ubuntu-20-04).

Ubuntu 18.04.5 was great but I'd prefer not to backdate at this point, which leaves me to consider installing Python 2.  Upon a quick Googling I found many sites that explain the steps to install Python 2 in Ubuntu 20.04 (ex https://linuxconfig.org/install-python-2-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux or https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-python-2-on-ubuntu-20-04), and most of these even include instructions on how to use `update-alternatives` to make `python` default to Python 2, which is a necessity in my case for supporting one of the legacy options I mentioned earlier.

I find it odd that something as major as installing an entire other version of Python does not cause problems with Ubuntu, since many Linux utilities today use Python.  On the other hand Python 2 is offered as an official package by Canonical https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python2 and they are generally very good about package integration.

At this time here are my questions:

1. Can anybody that has installed Python 2 in Ubuntu 20.04 clarify if this caused problems?  Are there any common applications that won't work after installing Python 2?  Any other "gotchas" I should know about or look out for pertaining to this?
2. If I continue with the instructions above (`update-alternatives` to make `python` default to Python 2) will that potentially cause problems?  Any "gotchas" pertaining to this additional step in particular?
3. Has anybody tried a Python 2 virtual environment configuration (without a Python 2 native install) in Ubuntu?  Is it really as easy as this page https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-python2-with-virtualenv-on-ubuntu/ makes it sound?  Will virtual environments work for supporting significant applications that call other scripts, use `python` (expecting it to be Python 2), span/fork other processes, etc?
4. If the native Python 2 install on Ubuntu 20.04 and/or the virtual environment options are problematic, are there any other good options I haven't covered here?

Comment: I in the early *focal* days needed to install `python2` to use scripts, and didn't experience any issues with it. The scripts though were ported to `python3` and my need for `python2` disappeared & I just stopped using it.  `python2` is still installed I note, but I haven't used it in months (*maybe even a year; I was using focal prior to its release*).  Refer to Thomas' answer

Comment: Forget about VMs for this purpose. The only thing a VM gives you is full kernel/HW isolation, which you really don't need for userspace stuff like this. Use your favourite container solution (Podman, Docker, `machinectl`, …) instead, where none of the downsides you mentioned apply.

Comment: @TooTea Containerization is only easier than a VM here if the applications do not have any graphical components. Running a GUI app inside a Docker container and using the host’s display is non-trivial and can be very error-prone at times because some things do not quite work correctly over a networked connection to the X server.

Comment: As a Rubyist, this always massively confuses me. Ruby 1.9 and Py3k happened around the same time, and back then, I predicted that the Python community's transition would be *much faster* and *much smoother* because: a) Python has the PEP process, so future changes are known before they are rolled out, whereas in Ruby, you just have to wait for the release of YARV to come out and discover the changes by yourself. b) Python has the `from __future__ import` feature. c) Python has the `2to3` and `3to2` tools. d) The changes in Ruby 1.9 were much more invasive than Python 3000.

Comment: And yet, much to my own surprise, the Ruby community completed the transition years ago, even though they never had automated tools for the transition, there is no feature that allows you to gradually migrate module-by-module, feature-by-feature, and the community as a whole seemed to be much less organized.

Comment: This is not an answer, but an important comment: **RUN AWAY**. You can safely close out that you are working on a successful project.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn It is actually pretty much trivial as long as you don't overdo the containerization. All you need is a glorified chroot (certainly no PID/net/user/… namespacing), pretty much just mounting a different version of `/usr` over your main system. That means all GUI apps in the "container" can still see the local X socket in `/tmp`, auth data in `$HOME`, all IPC mechanisms like DBus, and everything works smoothly. More or less what Flatpak/Snap is doing I guess. This is trivial to arrange with Podman, I never tried it with Docker, but I assume it should be doable there as well.

Comment: @TooTea It’s doable in Docker, but it requires a non-trivial amount of setup for the container in question.

Answer (score 10):

> 1. Can anybody that has installed Python 2 in Ubuntu 20.04 clarify if this caused problems? Are there any common applications that won't work after installing Python 2? Any other "gotchas" I should know about or look out for pertaining to this?

You can do this, but there may be issues with Python 2 in the near future - pay attention to my later sections of this post!

Installing `python2` by default SHOULD make `python` be equivalent to Python 2 - if it doesn't then...

> 2. If I continue with the instructions above (update-alternatives to make python default to Python 2) will that potentially cause problems? Any "gotchas" pertaining to this additional step in particular?

There's already packages for this - `python-is-python2` is the one you'll want.  Install that once you install Python 2.  That'll handle the linking for `python` to `python2.7`.

> 3. Has anybody tried a Python 2 virtual environment configuration (without a Python 2 native install) in Ubuntu? Is it really as easy as this page https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-python2-with-virtualenv-on-ubuntu/ makes it sound? Will virtual environments work for supporting significant applications that call other scripts, use python (expecting it to be Python 2), span/fork other processes, etc?

I don't use plain virtualenv to get Python installs that differ from the system Python.  I use [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for this, because it makes individual userspace installations of Python.  You *will* need the build dependencies for the `python` and `python2.7` installed - `sudo apt build-dep python python2.7` should do it.

> 4. If the native Python 2 install on Ubuntu 20.04 and/or the virtual environment options are problematic, are there any other good options I haven't covered here?

Neither the native install nor the PyEnv approach will break anything.  But there's quite a few things you need to be aware of.

#### Essentially... Python 2 Is Dead - both Upstream and in PyPA PIP (the `pip install ...` program)

(NOTE: Some distributions may provide **limited** support for Python 2, but everything that is still reliant on Python 2 and NOT being migrated to Python 3 should be frowned upon)

**Python PIP is not going to be supporting Python 2 as of four days ago with the 21.0 release of the underlying `pip` module**.  If you follow the PyEnv or individual separate Python 2 installation separate from System Python and `python-pip`'s install, **you will not be able to get Python modules for Python 2 anymore**.

Given that you're handling a legacy Python 2 program, **I would strongly recommend you work on rewriting the program for Python 3**.  You are going to run into a TON of issues going forward if you have to maintain this legacy program beyond a year or two since the EOL date of 2020 - support for Python 2 is phased out upstream, and with PIP no longer supporting Python 2 you're going to start running into **a ton** of problems going forward keeping Python 2 applications around.

For *most* programs it's not supremely hard to port Python 2 programs to Python 3.  If your dependent libraries (and NOT the underlying Python 2 code itself) are *only* Python 2 then you're going to run into long term support problems - and you REALLY should be looking to replace / upgrade the process.

Comment: It should be noted though that while Python2 is EOL by the PSF, there are distributions out there who will support Python2 for years to come (RHEL supports 2.7 at the very least until 2024). So depending where the program will actually be deployed Python2 can still be fine (although it still makes a ton of sense to port any currently deployed application to 3..). I would make sense to switch to one of those distros for development as well then.

Comment: @Voo except if they *need* newer Python Module deps (or even older legacy ones) such as from PyPI they actually are phasing out Python 2 and have for a while now - they will still face THAT problem as well regardless of distro - eventually old PIP versions will just not work anymore.

Comment: Sure, but a legacy application still on 2.x in 2021 probably doesn't need module updates (you should certainly make sure to keep copies of your dependencies though).

Comment: @Voo well *getting* old module versions will still break - if `pip` stops supporting Python 2 requests, then even *running* an old Python 2 app will require a lot more admin work to get the modules into the runtime space.  THAT is the other core problem that I think you're missing here too.  (That said, Py2 apps should REALLY be redeveloped for Py3 sooner than later)

Comment: Yeah that does sound like a problem. I assume that's why I explicitly mentioned keeping copies of the build dependencies in the previous comment.

Comment: @Voo which won't exist when Python 2.7 is eventually phased out from most/all distros.  But this is starting to get into a much larger argument.